# Padding and Margins in HTML?

Tags: html

This code probably looks like something out of your worst nightmares, but is anyone able to give me a lending hand? I'm attempting to use margin and padding in the Source Code instead of having to go into the CSS and create more than what I think is needed. I'm simply just trying to move the text over to the left a certain amount:

```
<li>
    <div class="member">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vSZyVru.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <h4>margin:left: 5px; padding: 5px; Bill Nye</h4>
            <p>
                Journalist reaseacher. 
            </p>
            <ol class="social">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Well, change `<h4>margin:left: 5px; padding: 5px;` to `<h4 style="margin:left: 5px; padding: 5px;">`.

Comment: Try to search for"HTML style Attribute". That probably does what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really do NOT want an external CSS file containing your CSS styling you could either define it within internal `<style>` tags or inline.

**Inline CSS**

Simply change your current styling from:

```
<h4>margin:left: 5px; padding: 5px; Bill Nye</h4>
```

to

```
<h4 style="margin-left: 5px; padding: 5px;">Bill Nye</h4>
```

**CSS within internal `<style>` tag**

You can define a `<style>` tag within your HTML page's `<head>` tag to define CSS styles. The following would be an example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            h4 {
              margin-left: 5px;
              padding: 5px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <!-- The rest of your HTML file content -->

</html>
```

This would apply the CSS style to all `<h4>` elements in your page. If you want to address only that single `<h4>` element, simply add an ID or class to the element like so `<h4 id="my-id">`. Then just reference that selector in the CSS:

```
#my-id {
  /* add your styling here */
}
```

You can find more basic info on defining CSS styles on the w3schools site [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Legend! Thanks a lot, really helpful :)

Comment: Just keep in mind, defining an external CSS file does wonders for organization and code cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using html non-breaking space:

`&nbsp;`

(that can be repeated) right before the text you want to move. This way you avoid loading external files and can be very useful in isolated cases (few pages). More info: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space